# How can I convert PagingSource type in the modular app in android?

Tags: android, pagination

I have a modular app that has 3 modules **feature** and **local** and **remote**.

I used pagination in the feature module that used **remoteMediator**.

My **remoteMediator** use PagingSource<Int, UserModel> but when I want to get data from the Dao, I have a problem:

remoteMediator neede PagingSource<Int, UserMode> but the local database return PagingSource<Int, UserEntity>.

How can i convert PagingSource<Int, UserEntity> to PagingSource<Int, UserModel>?

My Dao:

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ${Constants.USERS_TABLE}")
    fun getAllUsers(): PagingSource<Int, UserEntity>

}
```

My Repository:

```
 override fun getUsers(): Flow<PagingData<UserModel>> {
        val pagingSourceFactory = {
            githubDatabase.usersDao().getAllUsers()
        }

        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE),
            remoteMediator = AllUsersPagingSource(
                githubApi = githubApi,
                githubDatabase = githubDatabase,
                allUsersMapper = allUsersMapper,
                allUsersRemoteLocalMapper = allUsersRemoteLocalMapper
            ), pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
        ).flow
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Did you try to apply mapper on the return data?**
Use a mapper in a repository to map data from UserEntity to UserModel
Try something like this:
 `githubDatabase.usersDao().getAllUsers().map{ mapper.mapToModel(it) }`
I hope this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same problem. Currently, we can not apply any mapping to PagingSource, my solution is to apply the [transformation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform#convert-data) to the flow from Pager:

```
return Pager(
    config = PagingConfig(pageSize = ITEMS_PER_PAGE),
    remoteMediator = RemoteMediator<Int, UserEntity>(), // your mediator's Value type is UserEntity, not the UserModel
    pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
).flow.map { pagingData ->
    pagingData.map { userEntity ->
        userEntity.toUserModel() // convert UserEntity to UserModel
    }
}
```

Notice that the type of remote mediator is `RemoteMediator<Int, UserEntity >` (UserEntity, not UserModel).

Comment: This is genius! Thanks! By the way did you notice some performance issue with this approach?